# Predicting account balance based on historical data

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, autoregressive

Given the values of a bank account balance over time (see figure below as an example), how can one predict the account balance at a given date in the future ?

Should I just fit one linear regression model to the values of the i'th day of each month, in order to predict the value at the i'th date of future months ?

[image]